# How can I use CSS, HTML, and Python to add a box or container specifically around the inner elements (h1, h2) in a Streamlit app?

Tags: python, html, css, streamlit

As a beginner, I'm in the process of creating a simple Todo web app. I've developed three files so far: **web.py** (which contains the main code), **functions.py** (housing the functions), and **.streamlit/config.toml** (holding the theme configurations). Storing the todos in todos.txt file.

In **web.py** :

```
import streamlit as st
import functions

todos = functions.get_todos()


def add_todo():
    todo = st.session_state["new_todo"] + "\n"
    todos.append(todo)
    functions.write_todos(todos)


# Set page configuration using the theme config from config.toml
st.set_page_config(
    page_title="My Todo App",
    page_icon="✅",
)

# Add a container with a shadow effect using CSS
st.markdown(
    """
    <style>
    .box-with-shadow {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    </style>
    """,
    unsafe_allow_html=True
)

# Display the container and its elements
st.markdown('<div class="box-with-shadow">', unsafe_allow_html=True)

# Apply styles to individual elements using inline HTML and CSS
st.markdown('<h1>My Todo App</h1>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.markdown('<h2>This is my todo-app.</h2>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.markdown('<p>This app is to increase your productivity.</p>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

for index, todo in enumerate(todos):
    checkbox = st.checkbox(todo, key=todo)
    if checkbox:
        todos.pop(index)
        functions.write_todos(todos)
        del st.session_state[todo]
        st.experimental_rerun()

st.text_input(label=" ",
              placeholder="Add a new todo...",
              on_change=add_todo, key='new_todo')

st.markdown('</div>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(functions.get_todos())
```

In **functions.py** :

```
def get_todos(filepath="todos.txt"):
    """
    Read the text file and return the list of to-do items
    :param filepath:
    :return:
    """
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_local:
        todos_local = file_local.readlines()
    return todos_local


def write_todos(todos_arg, filepath="todos.txt"):
    """ Write the to-do items list in the file. """
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(todos_arg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_todos())
```

Could someone kindly review the code above and provide guidance on any improvements or potential issues? Specifically, I'm interested in optimizing the code structure and ensuring best practices for my Todo app.

While attempting to apply my understanding, I've added CSS and HTML to enclose elements within the designated box. However, I've encountere da challenge where the elements arent being enclosed as intended. It's possible that my logic contains errors. Ive consulted several related inquiries for a solution, but despite my efforts, I haven't yet pinpointed the exact resolution.

Comment: This kind of question may be better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Streamlit but, after looking through a few tutorials, I'm pretty sure constructing your document using `.markdown` and html strings is the wrong approach.

Comment: @Ouroborus, I indeed conducted a search and your observation is accurate. When dealing with a dynamic program, leveraging Streamlit's Python-based components is the preferable approach. Nevertheless, the central question remains unaltered: how exactly should this be achieved?

Comment: @Ouroborus This question was cross posted to Code Review, it is off-topic there because the code isn't working.

Comment: @Ouroborus No. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/286664

Answer (score -1):

- You are using the `session_state` object to store the new todo item. This is a good practice, as it allows you to keep track of the todo item even after the page is refreshed. However, you are not using the `session_state` object to store the checkbox state. This means that the checkbox state will be lost after the page is refreshed. You can fix this by storing the checkbox state in the `session_state` object as well.
- You are using the `experimental_rerun()` function to force a re-render of the page after the checkbox is unchecked. This is a good practice, as it ensures that the checkbox state is updated on the page. However, you can also use the `session_state` object to update the checkbox state, which would avoid the need to use the `experimental_rerun()` function.
- You are using inline HTML and CSS to style the elements in your app. This is a good way to quickly and easily style your app. However, it can be difficult to maintain and debug. You can improve the maintainability of your code by using a CSS framework.
- You are not using a consistent naming convention for your variables and functions. This can make your code more difficult to read and understand. You can improve the readability of your code by using a consistent naming convention.
- As for the issue with the CSS and HTML not enclosing the elements as intended, it is possible that there is a syntax error in your code. You can try debugging your code to find the error. You can also try using a different CSS framework.

Comment: just to clarify, I'm currently storing the todos within a todo.txt file, following the pattern illustrated in functions.py. Regarding the experimental_rerun() function you mentioned, I can't seem to locate it in my code. As for naming conventions, I've made an effort to choose descriptive names to enhance clarity (please feel free to correct me if necessary). Finally, for now, no visible errors have arisen.

Comment: Is this a ChatGPT answer? [Those are currently banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).